# What is the best way to code HTML table with multiple headers in between rows?

Tags: html, css, accessibility, screen-readers

What is the best way to code HTML table with multiple headers in between rows? I have created a decent HTML table. However, when I try to use the screen reader for 508 compliance, the screen reader reads all row headers (Header 1, Header 2, header 3) when I navigate through each row. Is there a way to avoid it? What am I missing?

Here is the fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/kq739m28/

```html
<p>Test</p>

<div style=" overflow-x: auto;">
  <table style=" width: 100%;">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>&#160;</td>
        <th>1</th>
        <th>2</th>
        <th>3</th>
        <th>4</th>
        <th>5</th>
        <th>6</th>
        <th>7</th>
        <th>8</th>
        <th>9</th>
      </tr>

    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="10" scope="colgroup" style=" background-color: #e0e0e0; text-align: left;">Header1</th>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <th style=" font-weight: 400; text-align: left;">dffddf</th>
        <td>✓</td>
        <td>✓</td>
        <td>✓</td>
        <td>✓</td>
        <td>&#160;</td>
        <td>&#160;</td>
        <td>✓</td>
        <td>✓</td>
        <td>✓</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <th style=" font-weight: 400; text-align: left;">fdfdfdf</th>
        <td>✓</td>
        <td>✓</td>
        <td>✓</td>
        <td>✓</td>
        <td>✓</td>
        <td>✓</td>
        <td>✓</td>
        <td>✓</td>
        <td>✓</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <th style=" font-weight: 400; text-align: left;">dffddf</th>
        <td align="center" style=" text-align: center; color: black;">&#160;</td>
        <td align="center" style=" text-align: center; color: black;">&#160;</td>
        <td align="center" style=" text-align: center; color: black;">&#160;</td>
        <td align="center" style=" text-align: center; color: black;">&#160;</td>
        <td align="center" style=" text-align: center; color: black;">&#160;</td>
        <td>✓</td>
        <td align="center" style=" text-align: center; color: black;">&#160;</td>
        <td align="center" style=" text-align: center; color: black;">&#160;</td>
        <td align="center" style=" text-align: center; color: black;">&#160;</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <th colspan="10" scope="colgroup" style=" background-color: #e0e0e0; text-align: left;">Header2</th>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <th style=" font-weight: 400; text-align: left;">5455445</th>
        <td>✓</td>
        <td>✓</td>
        <td>✓</td>
        <td>✓</td>
        <td align="center" style=" text-align: center; color: black;">&#160;</td>
        <td align="center" style=" text-align: center; color: black;">&#160;</td>
        <td>✓</td>
        <td>✓</td>
        <td>✓</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <th style=" font-weight: 400; text-align: left;">fdfggfgf</th>
        <td>✓</td>
        <td>✓</td>
        <td>✓</td>
        <td>✓</td>
        <td>✓</td>
        <td>✓</td>
        <td>✓</td>
        <td>✓</td>
        <td>✓</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <th colspan="10" scope="colgroup" style=" background-color: #e0e0e0; text-align: left;">Header3</th>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <th style=" font-weight: 400; text-align: left;">fgggf</th>
        <td>✓</td>
        <td>✓</td>
        <td>✓</td>
        <td>✓</td>
        <td>✓</td>
        <td>✓</td>
        <td>✓</td>
        <td>&#160;</td>
        <td>✓</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <th style=" font-weight: 400; text-align: left;">fgggfgf</th>
        <td>✓</td>
        <td>✓</td>
        <td>✓</td>
        <td>✓</td>
        <td>✓</td>
        <td>&#160;</td>
        <td>&#160;</td>
        <td>✓</td>
        <td>&#160;</td>
      </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Updated the question to format the code and make it a runnable snippet, and add the [tag:accessibility] and [tag:web-accessibility] tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use the ARIA `role="rowgroup"` attribute on separate `<tbody>` elements to specify the group of rows to which the header row must apply. Then you should also apply the `scope="rowgroup"` attribute to your individual header rows.

For example:

```
<table style="width: 100%;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>&#160;</td>
            <th>1</th>
            <th>2</th>
            <th>3</th>
            <th>4</th>
            <th>5</th>
            <th>6</th>
            <th>7</th>
            <th>8</th>
            <th>9</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody role="rowgroup">
        <tr>
            <th colspan="10" scope="rowgroup" style="background-color: #e0e0e0; text-align: left;">Header1</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>dffddf</th>
            <td>✓</td>
            <td>✓</td>
            <td>✓</td>
            <td>✓</td>
            <td>&#160;</td>
            <td>&#160;</td>
            <td>✓</td>
            <td>✓</td>
            <td>✓</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>fdfdfdf</th>
            <td>✓</td>
            <td>✓</td>
            <td>✓</td>
            <td>✓</td>
            <td>✓</td>
            <td>✓</td>
            <td>✓</td>
            <td>✓</td>
            <td>✓</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>dffddf</th>
            <td>&#160;</td>
            <td>&#160;</td>
            <td>&#160;</td>
            <td>&#160;</td>
            <td>&#160;</td>
            <td>✓</td>
            <td>&#160;</td>
            <td>&#160;</td>
            <td>&#160;</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody role="rowgroup">
        <tr>
            <th colspan="10" scope="rowgroup" style=" background-color: #e0e0e0; text-align: left;">Header2</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>5455445</th>
            <td>✓</td>
            <td>✓</td>
            <td>✓</td>
            <td>✓</td>
            <td>&#160;</td>
            <td>&#160;</td>
            <td>✓</td>
            <td>✓</td>
            <td>✓</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>fdfggfgf</th>
            <td>✓</td>
            <td>✓</td>
            <td>✓</td>
            <td>✓</td>
            <td>✓</td>
            <td>✓</td>
            <td>✓</td>
            <td>✓</td>
            <td>✓</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody role="rowgroup">
        <tr>
            <th colspan="10" scope="rowgroup" style=" background-color: #e0e0e0; text-align: left;">Header3</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>fgggf</th>
            <td>✓</td>
            <td>✓</td>
            <td>✓</td>
            <td>✓</td>
            <td>✓</td>
            <td>✓</td>
            <td>✓</td>
            <td>&#160;</td>
            <td>✓</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>fgggfgf</th>
            <td>✓</td>
            <td>✓</td>
            <td>✓</td>
            <td>✓</td>
            <td>✓</td>
            <td>&#160;</td>
            <td>&#160;</td>
            <td>✓</td>
            <td>&#160;</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I tested this code in Chrome 99 with JAWS 2022 and NVDA 2021 to make sure that the screen reader wasn't announcing all row headers each time I moved from column to column.

Here are some useful articles explaining how to implement the ARIA `rowgroup` role:

[W3C Techniques for WCAG 2.1: Using the scope attribute to associate header cells and data cells in data tables](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Techniques/html/H63.html)

[MDN Web Docs: ARIA: rowgroup role](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/Rowgroup_Role)

Comment: Thankyou!! It worked well. Somehow it was not announcing headers at all. So I just changed from rowgroup to colgroup. It announced it how I wanted. I have submitted the page to 508 compliance team for review. Hope it passes. Thankyou!!

Comment: @Superman no problem, glad I could help. Please feel free to mark this answer as correct if you think it solved your issue. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

You can make the screen reader skip it.

> Methods to Hide from Screen Readers:
> To hide text from a screen reader and display it visually, use the `aria-hidden attribute` and set it to true. [Source from Pluralsight](https://app.pluralsight.com/guides/how-to-hide-text-from-screen-readers)

```
<p aria-hidden="true">Visible text screen readers should ignore</p>
```

Comment: But presumably this content _is_ important to be read in certain contexts, no?  This would _completely_ hide it from users leveraging a screen reader.

Comment: I want the screen reader to read the headers, just not all together. I want it to read "Header1, 1, dffddf checkbox." Instead it is reading "Header1, Header2, Header3 1, dffddf checkbox."

Comment: @AlexanderNied I am not quite sure why you'd want the screen reader to skip it in any context. Still, this answers the "how to avoid it"-part. Maybe our screen readers are reading the table in different ways? I am using voiceover on mac and your table is being read perfectly fine for me

Comment: Here is an example I am trying to achieve: - Example1 
Table with two tier headers
https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/tables/irregular/

Comment: That's fair.  For what it's worth, [VoiceOver not reading table headings _may_ be a bug/idiosyncrasy of VoiceOver, not necessarily the "intended"/specced behavior](https://www.w3.org/WAI/GL/wiki/Failure_of_Success_Criterion_1.3.1_for_not_correctly_marking_up_table_headers#User_Agent_Notes). As it turns out screen readers are pretty varied in their behavior, making this sort of thing kind of devilish to solve, unfortunately.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't address the OP's question. Using `aria-hidden="true"` should only be considered for information or elements that aren't in any way pertinent to users, whereas the header information from the OP's table example is pertinent. It therefore shouldn't be hidden using ARIA. The OP is asking how to avoid the jumbled header row announcements, rather than how to avoid the header rows being announced altogether.